# render updated context of child in parent template

Tags: templates, django-templates, parent-child, django-cms

I'm trying access some variables in context of child from parent template. There is no problem with it but I need to access updated context.

My cms_plugins.py (child plugin render method):

```
...
context.update({
     'instance': instance,
     'address': address,
     'gps': gps,
})
return context
```

address and gps are parsed strings.

My base.html looks like:

```
...
{% for plugin in instance.child_plugin_instances %}
var position{{ plugin.pk }} = geocode("{{ plugin.address }}");
var marker{{ plugin.pk }}=new google.maps.Marker({
    title: "{{ plugin.titleMarker }}",
    position: position{{ plugin.pk }},
    icon: mapicon
});
marker{{ plugin.pk }}.setMap(map);
var infowindow{{ plugin.pk }} = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    disableAutoPan: true,
    content: "{% if plugin.titleMarker %}<p class='perex1' style='font-weight: bold;'>{{ plugin.titleMarker }}</p>{% endif %}"
    {% if plugin.nameOfPlace %}+ "{{ plugin.nameOfPlace }}</br>"{% endif %}
    {% if plugin.addressMarker %}+ "{{ plugin.addressMarker }}</br>"{% endif %}
    {% if plugin.zipcodeMarker %}+ "{{ plugin.zipcodeMarker }} {{ plugin.cityMarker }}</br></br>"{% endif %}
    {% if plugin.telMarker %}+ "<strong>TEL: </strong>{{ plugin.telMarker }}</br>"{% endif %}
    {% if plugin.faxMarker %}+ "<strong>FAX: </strong>{{ plugin.faxMarker }}</br>"{% endif %}
    {% if gps %}+ "<strong>GPS: </strong>{{ plugin.gps }}</br>"{% endif %}
});
...
```

I can't write this in child template and use `{{ render_template plugin }}` because it will wrap it in `<div class="cms-plugin cms-plugin-id">...</div>` and because these child plugins contains only java script, it throw errors on it.

Now, even if I write `{{ plugin.address }}` or `{{ address }}`(same with gps) nothing shows up. How can I access these variables? Or how can I append these variables into instance, that I can access them via plugin.name_of_variable?

EDIT:
I did some workaround. I created some parser function in JS for address and GPS... But I would really like to do that in backend instead of frontend. So, is it possible to do what I've asked?

Comment: I'm a bit unclear on what you're trying to do. Can you post your plugin definitions as well as the plugin templates?

Comment: sure, I will post templates in here, but right now I'm on vacation. So at least definition:
It is basically google map plugin using google map api v3. Main template defines type of map, centre of map, zoom and so on. Child template adds marker(location, content, behaviour and so on). So in for loop I'm trying to add script definition for marker.